# Search for user by email or by primary key of type uuid

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using typeorm with typescript and the postgresql driver

I have this code in my controller:

```js
const userRepository = getCustomRepository(UserRepositories);
const query = { by_email: {where: {email: user_receiver} }, by_uuid: user_receiver }
const isValidReceiver = user_receiver.includes("@") ? await userRepository.findOne(query.by_email) : await userRepository.findOne(query.by_uuid)
```

Is there any way to simplify this query or the checking if the user receiver is an email or a uuid?

Answer (score 0):

you use the following function, to check if is a valid email, `yup.js` or some other libraries to check it for you

```
const isEmail = (email: string) => {
      const regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    
      if (!regex.test(email)) {
        return false
      }
      
      return true
    }
```